# Visual Basic, new to coding. Need to make a list of 100 integers create a shuffled list of 70 results

Tags: vb.net, list, shuffle

I'm new to coding and I have got firmly stuck on this.

I've created a list in Visual Basic with

```
Dim integerStable As New List(Of Integer)()

integerStable.Add(0)
integerStable.Add(1)
integerStable.Add(2)
'through to integerStable.Add(99)
```

I'm trying to keep this list (it can be shuffled as long as all numbers stay in the list in general) and create a 2nd list where it only has 70 results from that shuffle.

I need that list, so I can call on it to perform some tasks for me later.

Can anyone help me work out how to do this?  Remember I'm new to coding, but I'll try to follow along.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient ways to create your list would be as follows:

```
Dim integerStable As New List(Of Integer)
For i = 1 To 100
    integerStable.Add(i)
Next
```

That at least should save you a lot of typing!!

You could also do the following:

```
Dim integerStable As New List(Of Integer)
Dim i As Integer
While i  <= 100
    integerStable.Add(i)
    i += 1
End While
```

**Note though that the latter example will give you 101 items as integer is initially set to 0 **

You also need to remember that the list will be 'indexed' from 0 NOT 1 which is an important thing to remember when it comes to manipulating the items with it.

Comment: Omg lol, you have no idea (well you might actually) how long it took to write it all out :p  I did at least copy paste a lot of it but I'll go remove the old 100 line list and replace it with the 4 line list :D

Any ideas how I make a list create a new list?  I can't find any documentation on it.  I need a separate list so I can delete and recreate in iterations after I pull the information, with out corrupting the original sample list, that will have other dependencies in the future.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more clearly just exactly what it is that you are trying to do, and the reasoning behind it.  it would make it much easier to point you in the correct direction.

Comment: absolutely.  I will put my pseudo code comments up for you to see, or I can invite you to the shared project if you find time to look directly at it.  It's a slot machine prototype to show case my knowledge of design, (but I have no code for it yet, I'm working on it tho!)  Ok, here goes.  Incoming, rusty pseudo code comments.

'On click button "spin!!!"

'disable all buttons.

'call up list "noPlayStartSymbols" (a list of png's for the slot start position.

'5 iterations of <
' call up list "100integers" and shuffle, print list of first 70 results

Comment: I tired to put comments in to show you, but it didn't format, and it's so bulky to read.  Is there a better way I can show you?

Answer (score 0):

It can be much simpler.

```
Private Shared PRNG As New Random
' 100 numbers starting at zero, in random order
Private listOnum As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).OrderBy(Function(x) PRNG.Next).ToList
' list of 70 numbers from list of 100
Private list70 As List(Of Integer) = listOnum.Take(70).ToList

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'did it work?
    Dim ct As Integer = 1
    For Each n As Integer In list70
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}. {1,3}", ct, n)
        ct += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Enumerable.Range takes two arguments.  The first is a start number and the second is a count, so in the example it created a list that started at 0 and ended with 99, 100 items.  The OrderBy just sorted that list by random numbers.

list70 is created by taking the first 70 items from listOnum.

The Random, PRNG, is created that way so that there is only ONE random that is only initialized once.  You can find many problems associated with the incorrect initialization of Random.

edit: Slightly different approach.

```
Private Shared PRNG As New Random
' 100 numbers starting at zero
Private listOnum As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList
' list of 70 random numbers from list of 100
Private list70 As List(Of Integer) = listOnum.OrderBy(Function(x) PRNG.Next).Take(70).ToList

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'did it work?
    Dim ct As Integer = 1
    For Each n As Integer In list70
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}. {1,3}", ct, n)
        ct += 1
    Next
    'recreate list of 70
    list70 = listOnum.OrderBy(Function(x) PRNG.Next).Take(70).ToList
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh crap, my mind just melted.  Strangely it looks correct to me, but I don't understand it at all. :-)  I'll save, and edit my doc, and have a look at it in action.

Thanks so much for that help to both of you.

Comment: @envisage - added some explanation, hope it helps your mind melting ;)

Comment: @dbasnett  That's an interesting approach.  But how random is it?  I just played with this in Linqpad (truly wonderful as a quick test environment) and noticed the same numbers coming up in the same order.

Comment: @DomSinclair - well the random number generator in .Net isn't awful, but it isn't great either.  If you are getting the same numbers using the example as posted then it is Linqpad.

Comment: @DomSinclair -  If you are just running it once and repeatedly clicking the button then the numbers WILL be the same.  See edit.

Comment: @dbasnett  No not Linqpad, my fault entirely , fouled up the iteration at the start to regenerate the random numbers.